# What should I take into consideration when using margin & padding to space elements?

Tags: html, css, padding, margin

I have been tasked with modifying the layout of a site so that it meets the criteria of the client's corporate style guide.

The guide is requiring that I ensure certain elements are spaced [X]px from other elements, and that elements of this type are lined up with elements of that type.

So as I'm doing this, I can see that the existing spacings are defined in some cases using `padding`, and in other cases using `margin`.

Is there a preferred way of doing this? When should I use one in favour of the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That really depends somehow. Margin and Padding are two different things. However in some cases you will not notice a difference.

A figure which shows you the difference:

[image]

Source: http://www.edition-w3c.de/TR/1998/REC-CSS2-19980512/bilder/boxdim.gif

So for example: If you want to define the space between the border and your content you will only achieve this with padding(while having a visible border).

Answer (score 2):

In layman terms.

If you have two div's next to one another, the space between the two is referred to as the margin.

If you have text inside a div, the space between the edge of the div(top,right,bottom,left) and text is referred to as padding.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is best explained visually.

Try this out:

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    body { background-color: #E342FF; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
    #mydiv { border: 2px solid #000000; width: 50%; height: 20%; margin: 50px 0 0 50px; }
    #mydiv2 { border: 2px solid #000000; width: 50%; height: 20%; padding: 50px 0 0 50px; }  
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mydiv">
</div>
<div id="mydiv2">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

You should see that the margin is simply moving the div, and the padding is actually making it larger.